# What data type should I use to represent money in C#?

Tags: c#

In C#, what data type should I use to represent monetary amounts? Decimal? Float? Double? I want to take in consideration: precision, rounding, etc.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx):

> The Decimal value type represents
>   decimal numbers ranging from positive
>   79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335
>   to negative
>   79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335.
>   ***The Decimal value type is appropriate
>   for financial calculations requiring
>   large numbers of significant integral
>   and fractional digits and no round-off
>   errors.*** The Decimal type does not
>   eliminate the need for rounding.
>   Rather, it minimizes errors due to
>   rounding.

Neither [`System.Single` (`float`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) nor [`System.Double` (`double`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) are <del>precise enough</del> capable of representing high-precision floating point numbers without rounding errors.

Comment: I've upvoted this, but I take issue with the final claim. It's not that float/double aren't precise enough - it's just that they use an inappropriate base for money. You could have a 512 bit floating binary point value with more actual *precision* than decimal - but it still wouldn't be appropriate because it couldn't represent decimal values such as 0.1 exactly.

Comment: My mistake - I mixed meanings in my answer.  I used "precise" in my final statement not to mean "mathematical precision" but rather to express that a rounded number (1 in this example) is "less precise" than (0.99999_) when the number assigned to the variable was in fact 0.9999_.  Poor choice of words on my part...

Comment: Yes, even a float is _precise_ enough. The problem comes when converting from decimal to binary and back. The two different bases have different sets of irrational numbers.

Comment: I still don't agree with your last line. I'd say: "Any floating point system that relies on a binary mantissa is incapable of representing all decimal hundredths as rational numbers.

Comment: Nosredna, you are running into problems here because I think you have a misunderstanding of what "irrational" means. Irrationality is invariant over choice of base; an exact real value is either irrational or it isn't. Choice of base is irrelevant.  The distinction you actually want to be making here has nothing to do with rationality but rather has to do with _representation error_.

Comment: Eric, good point. 1/10 is representable in decimal with a fixed number of digits, but not in binary. In binary it's a repeating fraction.

Comment: What you should be saying is that any *finite* floating point system with a binary mantissa is incapable of *exactly* representing all decimal hundredths. That is, *without accruing representation error*.  For more analysis of basic issues in representation error in floating point arithmetic, you might want to see the series of articles I wrote on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Floating+Point+Arithmetic/default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use decimal and money in the DB if you're using SQL.

Answer (score 4):

In C#, the Decimal type actually a struct with overloaded functions for all math and comparison operations in base 10, so it will have less significant rounding errors.  A float (and double), on the other hand is akin to scientific notation in binary.  As a result, Decimal types are more accurate when you know the precision you need.

Run this to see the difference in the accuracy of the 2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace FloatVsDecimal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Decimal _decimal = 1.0m;
            float _float = 1.0f;
            for (int _i = 0; _i < 5; _i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("float: {0}, decimal: {1}", 
                                _float.ToString("e10"), 
                                _decimal.ToString("e10"));
                _decimal += 0.1m;
                _float += 0.1f;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) is the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Money Type for the CLR](http://moneytype.codeplex.com/).  It is a custom value type (struct) that also supports currencies and handles rounding off issues.

Comment: I was reading "Adaptive code via C#" book (from 2014) and it says: "it is not advisable to use the decimal type to represent currency values (...). Instead a Money (url same as in the above) value type should be used. I was confused as I had always been told to use decimal. The author doesn't argue why we shouldn't use decimal. 
Based on that and what George wrote, I guess decimal is the way to go.

Comment: @Marshall My guess would be because `decimal` doesn't carry any information about the currency we're dealing with. Dollars? Euros? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

In C# You should take "**Decimal**" to represent monetary amounts.

Answer (score 0):

For something quick and dirty, any of the floating point primitive types will do.

The problem with `float` and `double` is that neither of them can represent 1/10 accurately, occasionally resulting in surprising trillionths of a cent. You've probably heard of the infamous 10¢ + 20¢. More realistically, try calculating a 6% sales tax on three items valued at $39.99 each pre-tax.

Also, `float` and `double` have values like negative infinity and NaN that are of no use whatsoever for representing money. So `decimal`, which can represent 1/10 precisely would seem to be the best choice.

However, `decimal` doesn't carry any information about what currency we're dealing with. Does the amount $29.89, for example, equal €29.89? Is $29.89 > €29.89? How do I make sure these amounts are displayed with the correct currency symbols?

If these sorts of details matter for your program, then you should either use a third-party library or create your own `CurrencyAmount` class (or whatever you want to call it).

But if that sort of thing doesn't matter to the program, you can just use a floating point type. Or maybe even integers (e.g., my blackjack implementation in Java asks the player to enter a wager in whole dollars).