# Arithmetic overflow error for type money

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting sql exception (Arithmetic overflow error) for type money.How to set min and max value for money in c#. my sql type is money and C# datatype is double. Range of money is (-922,337,203,685,477.5808) to (922,337,203,685,477.5807).

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693372/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008826/what-data-type-should-i-use-to-represent-money-in-c

Comment: use decimal in c# code

Comment: It is a bad idea to map `money` to `double` - surely `decimal` would be a better choice?

Comment: What line of code is actually causing the exception? Are you passing something like `Double.MaxValue`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**decimal**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) for money operations.
[**Decimal**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) - specific type which is what you need when it comes to money manipulations. So if it is important for you to have precisely correct results - use it. Otherwise - double is fine.

---

**double** (System.Double) *±5.0 x 10-324 to ±1.7 x 10308 with 15 or 16 significant figures*
**decimal** (System.Decimal)    *±1.0 x 10-28 to ±7.9 x 1028 with 28 or 29 significant figures*

Answer (score 0):

Don't use double - use decimal for currency representation in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Use `decimal` instead; if you specifically want to set the min/max values, then:

```
const decimal Min = -922337203685477.5808M, Max = 922337203685477.5807M;
```

personally, I would suggest *not* to mess with the min/max too much, though. A `null` is probably clearer than an actual value in those cases.

Alternatively, there is the `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlMoney` type, which has `MinValue` and `MaxValue` - personally I'd try to avoid leaking implementation details (such as `SqlMoney`) into your domain model, though.